# Enabling typescript for Asp.net Core ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, react-typescript

I created an asp.net core Reactjs project via Visual Studio 2022.
Unfortunately everything is in javascript (not typescript).

How can i enable typescript for this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile TypeScript code with NuGet.

First, Add TypeScript support with NuGet : `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild`.

Then, Add the `tsconfig.json` file to the project root. You can use this file to configure options for the TypeScript compiler.Like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js"
  },
  "include": [
    "scripts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Lastly,  Add TypeScript (.ts) or TypeScript JSX (.tsx) files to your project, and then add TypeScript code.

For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/compile-typescript-code-nuget?view=vs-2022) and this [link](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/07/05/aspnetcore-hmr/).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: So this worked wonderfully. However it seems when i runt he web app it is not able to know anything about the components which i converted (renamed) to TSX.